# How to extract all <li> elements under <ul>

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to extract all `<li>` element text that are under `<ul>` for which I tried

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(("//div[@class='left width50']/p/b/ul"))
len(elem)
```

gives '0' or empty list.

here is the html source

```
<div class="left width50">
                            <p><b>Features:</b></p>
                            <ul>
                                    <li>Easy spray application</li>
                                    <li>Excellent bonding properties</li>
                                    <li>Single package</li>
                                    <li>Mixed with clean potable water at job site</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

HERE is the [link](http://www.carboline.com/products/) of the website

How to go about it any suggestions?

Comment: remove `/p/b`  this is not needed. Or use this as css selector - `#borderForGrid > div.left.width50 > ul`

Comment: @Kaushik how do I make a use of `css selector` ?

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#borderForGrid > div.left.width50 > ul')` Read the [link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) also

Comment: I used Xpath `a=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="borderForGrid"]/div[1]/ul')` , but it has ' ' elements

Comment: You need to iterate it to get the `li` values.

Comment: and for your kind information the page contains duplicate `ids` which is not a expected thing in normal web page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you're trying to find the path after the `p` and `b` tag. that will look something like this.

```
<div class="left width50">
    <p><b>Features:<ul>
            <li>Easy spray application</li>
            <li>Excellent bonding properties</li>
            <li>Single package</li>
            <li>Mixed with clean potable water at job site</li>
    </ul></b></p>

</div>
```

But your code is different in HTML.

So you should look around without the `p` and `b` tag.

Here is the quick help you can take from chrome. Go to developer option using `f12 key` and navigate to elements tab and then right click on the element which you want to find out and select the selector value.

You can read more about what are the ways to find the element [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

If you want to use the `xPath` this is right xpath for you - `//*[@id="borderForGrid"]/div[1]/ul`

**Extraction Process**

Once you'll get all the `ul` this will help you to get all the `li` text

```
all_li = all_ul_from_xpath.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for li in all_li:
    text = li.text
    print (text)
```

Working code for reference.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.carboline.com/products/")



elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="borderForGrid"]/div[1]/ul')

all_li = elem.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for li in all_li:
    text = li.text
    print (text)
```

**Output**

[image]

[image]

Comment: this gives correct answer, but how to iterate this for entire product list, should I change `//*[@id="borderForGrid"]/div[2]/ul` for every item?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you wanted to extract all `<li>` element's text that are associated with `<h5>` tag with text as **A/D TC-55 SEALER** and to achieve that you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-brands='Southwest'][data-types='Acrylics'] div.left.width50 ul>li")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h5//a[text()='A/D TC-55 SEALER']//following::div[1]//ul//li")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Considering your solution `print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h5//a[text()='A/D TC-55 SEALER']//following::div[1]//ul//li")))])` is limited if the text is `A/D TC-55 SEALER` what if I want it for other text like `CARBOCRYLIC 3356-1`

Comment: @deepesh Observe the HTML you have provided, which exclusively points towards **A/D TC-55 SEALER** section. Hence was my answer. Glad that you got an accepted solution.

Comment: Thank you @DebanjanB !, I solved my problem using hints from **Kaushik** answer, but it seems it doesn't work when those list are empty. so I came to using your solution, which specifically uses the <a> text name.

Answer (score 0):

There's is no element with the xpath :

```
//div[@class='left width50']/p/b/ul
```

`left width50` has 500 web element associated with it. So does `//div[@class='left width50']/p/b`

That's why you are getting 0 while doing len().

Instead try replacing it with this xpath

```
//a[text()='A/D Firefilm III']/../following-sibling::div[1]/descendant::li
```