# using Selenium to get texts inside 'ul' tag?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Please help me to find the solution to get the text inside 'ul' tag.

I want to get the information which is separated with commas like: 'Contains Enzymatically Active B-Vitamins, Dietary Supplement, Non-GMO LE Certified'

website link: https://ca.iherb.com/pr/Life-Extension-BioActive-Complete-B-Complex-60-Vegetarian-Capsules/67051

picture: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbymH.png)

This is the HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li>Contains Enzymatically Active B-Vitamins
  </li>
  <li>Dietary Supplement
  </li>
  <li>Non-GMO LE Certified
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: get text from all `li` and use `",".join(list_of_li)`

Comment: this will help [How to extract all <li> elements under <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421690/how-to-extract-all-li-elements-under-ul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver

link = 'https://ca.iherb.com/pr/Life-Extension-BioActive-Complete-B-Complex-60-Vegetarian-Capsules/67051'

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.get(link)
    elements = ', '.join([item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[itemprop='description'] > ul:nth-of-type(1) > li")])
    print(elements)
```

Output:

```
Contains Enzymatically Active B-Vitamins, Dietary Supplement, Non-GMO LE Certified
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the texts e.g. *Contains Enzymatically Active B-Vitamins*, *Dietary Supplement* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and printing the list:

  ```
  driver.get('https://ca.iherb.com/pr/Life-Extension-BioActive-Complete-B-Complex-60-Vegetarian-Capsules/67051')
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[itemprop='description']>ul li")])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Contains Enzymatically Active B-Vitamins', 'Dietary Supplement', 'Non-GMO LE Certified ', 'Promotes healthy metabolism of glucose, fat & alcohol', 'Supports the healthy energy production your body needs', 'Encourages healthy organ function, cognitive health & more', 'Helps inhibit potential vitamin B deficiency']
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and printing the elements in a comma seperated string:

  ```
  driver.get('https://ca.iherb.com/pr/Life-Extension-BioActive-Complete-B-Complex-60-Vegetarian-Capsules/67051')
  print(', '.join([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@itemprop='description']/ul//li")]))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Contains Enzymatically Active B-Vitamins, Dietary Supplement, Non-GMO LE Certified , Promotes healthy metabolism of glucose, fat & alcohol, Supports the healthy energy production your body needs, Encourages healthy organ function, cognitive health & more, Helps inhibit potential vitamin B deficiency
  ```

---

To extract the texts e.g. *Contains Enzymatically Active B-Vitamins*, *Dietary Supplement* ideally you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and printing the list:

  ```
  driver.get('https://ca.iherb.com/pr/Life-Extension-BioActive-Complete-B-Complex-60-Vegetarian-Capsules/67051')
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[itemprop='description']>ul li")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Contains Enzymatically Active B-Vitamins', 'Dietary Supplement', 'Non-GMO LE Certified ', 'Promotes healthy metabolism of glucose, fat & alcohol', 'Supports the healthy energy production your body needs', 'Encourages healthy organ function, cognitive health & more', 'Helps inhibit potential vitamin B deficiency']
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and printing the elements in a comma seperated string:

  ```
  driver.get('https://ca.iherb.com/pr/Life-Extension-BioActive-Complete-B-Complex-60-Vegetarian-Capsules/67051')
  print(', '.join([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@itemprop='description']/ul//li")))]))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Contains Enzymatically Active B-Vitamins, Dietary Supplement, Non-GMO LE Certified , Promotes healthy metabolism of glucose, fat & alcohol, Supports the healthy energy production your body needs, Encourages healthy organ function, cognitive health & more, Helps inhibit potential vitamin B deficiency
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can always get all elements `li`, get text from all these elements and use `", ".join(elements)`

---

Code for your small example

```
text = '''
<ul>
  <li>Contains Enzymatically Active B-Vitamins
  </li>
  <li>Dietary Supplement
  </li>
  <li>Non-GMO LE Certified
  </li>
</ul>'''

import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + text)

elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

elements = [i.text for i in elements]

print(", ".join(elements))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from shutil import which
chrome_path = which('chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chrome_path)

li_eliments = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

elements = []
for e in li_eliments.text:
    elements.append(e)
print(", ".join(elements))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty so Selenium is for web automation, but data scraping (like what it seems like you're trying to do) is more for requests, and beautiful soup. There have been posts about using Selenium that work, but it is easier to use these so you don't have to launch a web browser to do it like for selenium.

```
r = requests.get("https://ca.iherb.com/pr/Life-Extension-BioActive-Complete-B-Complex-60-Vegetarian-Capsules/67051")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
list_items = soup.find('div', itemprop="description")
found = str(re.findall(r'itemprop="description"><ul><li>(\D+)', str(list_items)))
```

This take just a second whereas the other methods can take much longer to load a browser and navigate to the website for this information. Once you get this information and use regex to find the appropriate tag, you can use regex to clean it up just the text.

```
newfound = re.sub(r"</li>|[\[']", '', found)
newfound2 = re.sub(r"<li>", ', ', newfound)
stripped = newfound2.split('\\xa0', 1)[0]
```

The lines `itemprop="description"><ul><li>` and `\xa0` are both from viewing the source of the page and finding the list element there.
Here's some info on regex: https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html